# How can I set my ASP.NET Core web app to be "always running" in local development?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am in the process of converting a set of web applications from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core.

Under the old ASP.NET, our applications were typically set up to run under "Local IIS" at a specific port and route. The benefit of this was that you could have multiple applications checked out and running locally without having to explicitly start or debug them all. After making a code change and rebuilding, IIS would spin up a new app domain and you could immediately start hitting the up-to-date code.

In contrast, all the ASP.NET Core apps I've seen so far use IIS Express instead of local IIS (as specified in launchSettings.json). How can I configure local IIS (or at least equivalent behavior)?

Comment: It's almost the second result from Google, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @lexli does this work with apps that are asp.net core but still targeting .net framework? I see a number of mentions of the AspNetCore IIS module which I thought didn’t support framework